# "null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.RNShare.FACEBOOK')" Import raising Issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg, react-native-share

I'm currently trying to build an App with React Native in which the user can enter data, generate a QR-Code and then also share that same QR-Code.

Entering the Data and generating the QR-Code is working as intended. However the sharing is what's making me struggle. Currently i have the Data saved as normal vars and display the QR-Code with "react-native-qrcode-svg". For the sharing part I'm using "react-native-share".

The latter is giving me this error:

`TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.RNShare.FACEBOOK')`

My Code:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
       <QRCode
          value={JSON.stringify({test: 'testdata'})}
          getRef={c => (this.svg = c)}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.saveQRCode}>
          <View style={styles.instructions}>
            <Text>Share QR code</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

saveQRCode = () => {
  this.svg.toDataURL(this.callback);
};


callback = (dataURL) => {
  console.log(dataURL);
  let shareImageBase64 = {
    title: 'React Native',
    url: `data:image/png;base64,${dataURL}`,
    subject: 'Share Link', //  for email
  };
  Share.open(shareImageBase64).catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have an expo project that's been ejected, and I got past this by stopping metro, running `npx pod-install`, and then uninstalling the app from the simulator before firing everything back up.

Also reference these issues for help:

https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share/issues/322

https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share/issues/837

Answer (score 0):

Try to close and rebuild the app using 'react-native run-android'.
it worked for me.

Comment: you can just comment this. This is not valid answer

Comment: then it's crash in ios